# Check for arrays when looping through C# Object Properties

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, oop

I've currently looping through a C# object to dissect the properties, as the objects used in the form's constructor can have different properties.

This is my current loop

```
foreach (var media in MediaItem.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    txtDetails.Text += media.Name + " - " + media.GetValue(MediaItem, null) + "\r\n";
}
```

It works for String, Int and Double values but when it reaches an array it returns System.String[], rather than the values.

How can I detect when the value is an array in the loop, and then return the values. I was thinking a nested for loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that you can start with:

```
public static string FormatData(object data)
{
    Array array = data as Array;

    if (array != null) //If this is an array, then join individual values seperated by ", "
    {
        return string.Join(", ", array.Cast<object>());
    }

    return data.ToString(); //otherwise, call ToString
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
foreach (var media in MediaItem.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    txtDetails.Text += media.Name + " - " + FormatData( media.GetValue(MediaItem, null)) + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes! It appears to have worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.